# Implementing a grid of buttons on iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, grid, uicollectionview, calculator

What would be the best way to implement a button layout similar to the following pictures?

I was reading up on creating a custom UIView or UIControl, but then I started to think that maybe a custom UICollectionViewLayout would be better. I need to have the flexibility to make some of the buttons take up the space of two or more buttons (such as a larger button for the "equals" sign).

I was thinking that NSMatrix would work great, but it's not implemented in iOS.

**Can I get some advice on what would be the best way to approach this?**

Thanks in advance!

[image: Calc Pro from Panoramic Software]
[image: Calculator HD Pro 1.7 from Cider Software] [image: Calculator HD Pro 1.7 from Cider Software]

Comment: Go with `UICollectionView`.

Comment: Can anyone explain how I would go about getting 1 button to span multiple rows or colums (such as the "=" button above)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UICollectionView that is very useful for gridview.So i'm giving you a link so please read n implement it.

1. http://www.cnblogs.com/simonshi2012/archive/2012/10/08/2715136.html
2. http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12
3. https://github.com/AshFurrow/UICollectionViewExample

Comment: Providing only a list of links is frowned upon. Because [link rot](http://www.jwz.org/blog/2015/02/scene-missing/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use UICollectionView if you are willing to support only iOS 6 and above. Or else there are many implementations of custom grid view like [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView). Or try [these](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=grid).